# delete column from table with id in node js with TypeORM

Tags: node.js, api, typeorm

I am having issue as follows:

> ```
> UserCtrl.ts
> ```

```
@Delete('/:id')
public delete( @Param('id') id: string): Promise<void> {
    if (this.lengthValidator(id)) {
            return Promise.reject(new OfferInvalidError(400, 'Invalid ID supplied'));
    } else {
        return this.userService.delete(id);
    }
}
```

> ```
> userService.ts
> ```

```
public delete(id: string): Promise<void> {
    return this.userRepository.removeById(id);
}
```

with this flow I am able to delete entry from table, but on return it sending me as:

> Not Found Error message

But I have to send proper message to user, so where I needs to add response ?

As I am new with Node JS I am struggling with this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally able to find solution,
I am not sure this is correct way to provide response to user but it worked for me:

```
    public delete( @Param('id') id: string): Promise<any> {
    if (this.lengthValidator(id)) {
            return Promise.reject(new OfferInvalidError(400, 'Invalid ID supplied'));
    } else {
        const isDeleted = this.userService.delete(id);
    if(isDeleted){
       return {success:'user has been deleted'}
    }
    }
}
```

So in short I have changed controller function's return type and added custom response to return function.

Answer (score 0):

use ! sign in if condition might be helpful

```
public delete( @Param('id') id: string): Promise<any> {
    if (!this.lengthValidator(id)) {
            return Promise.reject(new OfferInvalidError(400, 'Invalid ID supplied'));
    } else {
        const isDeleted = this.userService.delete(id);
    if(isDeleted){
       return {success:'user has been deleted'}
    }
    }
}
```